# Controlled form elements within a HOC in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have made simple components for inputs, textarea, etc., and a few HOCS to extend functionality without polluting the base component. However, I have discovered a little too late that when I make an input control, the changes in the value prop trigger a rerender which destroys the old input and rerenders it which causes it to lose focus. Here's an example of one of those HOCS in case I am misunderstanding:
I have made simple components for inputs, textarea, etc., and a few HOCS to extend functionality without polluting the base component. However, I have discovered a little too late that when I make an input control, the changes in the value prop trigger a rerender which destroys the old input and rerenders it which causes it to lose focus. Here's an example of one of those HOCS in case I am misunderstanding:

```
import { ComponentType } from 'react'
import styles from './withClearButton.module.scss'
import { Button } from '../../../../Button/Button'
import { Icon } from '../../../../Icon/Icon'

type InjectedProps = {
  onClearButtonClick?: () => void
}

export function withClearButton<BaseProps>(Component: ComponentType<BaseProps>) {
  type HocProps = BaseProps & InjectedProps

  const hocComp = (props: HocProps) => {
    const handleClear = () => {
      if (props.onClearButtonClick) {
        props.onClearButtonClick()
      }
    }

    return (
      <div className={styles.base}>
        <Component {...(props as any)} />
        <Button className={styles.button} onClick={handleClear} appearance="icon">
          <Icon icon={'ri-close-line'} />
        </Button>
      </div>
    )
  }

  hocComp.displayName = `withClearButton(${Component.displayName || Component.name || 'Component'})`

  return hocComp
}
```

Is there a smarter way to do this, or an alternative that lets me add this type of content without having to touch the base component while still being able to use it as if it were a native input component?
Is there a smarter way to do this, or an alternative that lets me add this type of content without having to touch the base component while still being able to use it as if it were a native input component?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that simply memoizing the result of the HOC before use, instead of the function the HOC itself returns, was enough to solve my problem:

```
const InputWithClearButton = useMemo(() => withClearButton(Input), []);
```

Or, better yet, move the whole line outside the component where it is being used to avoid unnecessary memoization.